# Integral of Wiener process with respect to time, as opposed to the stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Typically in stochastic integrals, it is common to have integrals with respect to the Wiener increment $dW(t)$.

For example

$$
\int_{0}^{t}W(t)dW(t) = \frac{W^{2}(t)}{2}-\frac{t}{2}
$$

by Ito's lemma. But, how does one go about computing

$$
\int_{0}^{t}W(t^{\prime})dt^{\prime}
$$

? I know that $dW(t)^{2}\equiv dt$ but I am not sure how to proceed integrating

$$
\int_{0}^{t} W(t^{\prime})\sqrt{dW(t^{\prime})}.
$$

What should be the approach here?

Comment: Hello. I've edited your post to add to the title another detail about your question that makes it more interesting at a glance - a user might have looked at the old title and thought you were talking about a normal stochastic integral. If you don't like this, feel free to change it.

Comment: The ordinary Riemann integral $
\int_{0}^{t}W(t^{\prime})dt^{\prime}
$ cannot be computed explicitly. It has nothing to do with stochastic integration.

Comment: $X_t =\int_{0}^{t}W(t^{\prime})dt^{\prime}$ is a random variable, it doesn't have a closed-form expression as far as I know, but with Itô's lemma, you can rewrite it as the integral of a determinstic function against $dW_{t'}$ and check some of its properties : for instance you can show that it is a Gaussian process and compute its mean and variance easily.

Comment: @StratosFair Can you elaborate more on this? What are the statistical properties of $X_t$? Is $X_t \sim N(0,t)$ since $W_{t} \sim N(0,t)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4573145/195378) of your another question, you have
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^tW_t'dt' &= \int_0^t(t-u)dW_u  \\
\end{align}$$
and then you can determine easily the law of this integral
$$\int_0^tW_t'dt' \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\int_0^t(t-u)^2du   \right)$$